# Element wise multiplication of a 3D matrix by a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, elementwise-operations

Consider the following 2 matrices: A = 3x3x3 and B = 3x3. Is it possible to perform an element wise multiplication between each slice of A and the kernel B without using a for loop? My current implementation is as follows:

```
for i = 1:3
    C = A(:,:,i) .* B(:,:);
end
```

where C is some output matrix

Answer (score 2):

As @Divakar suggested, bsxfun did the trick:

```
C = bsxfun(@times, A, B);
```